# Segue to next view controller after successful sign up

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I've searched and searched and searched but not found a solution. The sign up works but will not segue to the next view controller. Heres my code:

```
import UIKit
import Parse
import Bolts

class SignUpVC: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var profilePictureIV: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var firstNameTF: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var lastNameTF: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var newUsernameTF: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var newPasswordTF: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var emailTF: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var phoneNumberTF: UITextField!

@IBAction func setProfilePicture(sender: AnyObject) {
    let myPickerController = UIImagePickerController()
    myPickerController.delegate = self
    myPickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary
    self.presentViewController(myPickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

@IBAction func signUpButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    let spinner: UIActivityIndicatorView = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 150, 150)) as UIActivityIndicatorView

    if firstNameTF.text != "" &&  lastNameTF.text != "" && newUsernameTF.text != "" && newPasswordTF.text != "" && emailTF.text != "" && phoneNumberTF.text != "" {

        let newUser = PFUser()

        if let profilePictureImage = profilePictureIV?.image {
            let profilePicture = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(profilePictureImage, 1)!
            let profilePictureImageFile = PFFile(data: profilePicture)
            newUser["profilePicture"] = profilePictureImageFile
        }
        newUser["firstName"] = firstNameTF.text
        newUser["lastName"] = lastNameTF.text
        newUser.username = newUsernameTF.text
        newUser.password = newPasswordTF.text
        newUser.email = emailTF.text
        newUser["phoneNumber"] = phoneNumberTF.text

        newUser.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (succeeded: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if let error = error {
                spinner.startAnimating()
                self.alert("Opps", textMessage: (error.localizedDescription))
            } else {
                spinner.startAnimating()
                self.alert("Congratualtion!", textMessage: "Success, your account has been created.")
                self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showMessages", sender: self)
            }
        }
    } else {
        alert("Hmm...", textMessage: "If you want an account, please fill in the blanks.")
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    self.navigationController!.navigationBar.hidden = false
}

func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
    profilePictureIV.image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}

func alert(textTitle: String, textMessage: String) {
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: textTitle, message: textMessage, preferredStyle: .Alert)
    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil))
    self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}


/*
// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
// Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
// Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

}
```

If i play the `self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showMessages", sender: self)` line anywhere else then when i run the program and press the signup button it will directly go to in the messages view controller without any signup required.

Comment: You shouldn't issue a modal alert before you try to `performSegueWithIdentifier` to the next screen.  Remove this and see what happens, otherwise describe what happens when you do sign up.

Comment: As @Paulw11 remove the alert and then perform the segue, if u still want the alert before showing the next VC, add a completion handler or tap handler block to the dismiss button of the Alert so that you can perform the segue in that block.

Comment: Ah, thank you @Paulw11 and @iamyogish! I just switched the two lines and it worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as Paulw11 said , Try to remove alert message :-

```
       if let error = error {
            spinner.startAnimating()
            self.alert("Opps", textMessage: (error.localizedDescription))
        } else {
            spinner.startAnimating()
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showMessages", sender: self)

          }
```

or You can call the handler in your code.

```
          if let error = error {
            spinner.startAnimating()
            self.alert("Opps", textMessage: (error.localizedDescription))
        } else {
            spinner.startAnimating()
            var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Welcome", message: "Login", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title:"OK", style: .Default, handler:  { action in self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showMessages", sender: self) }

          }
```

Comment: It's giving an error, I can't use the `addAction(...)` method on the `alert`

Comment: Yes, I just switched both the lines so the alert comes after the segue, it worked perfectly! @Chathuranga Silva

Comment: In the second option just add : -   var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Welcome", message: "Login", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

Answer (score -1):

You can not pass self as a argument in side the block.

so create a method to call a segue

```
@IBAction func signUpButton(sender: AnyObject) {
  let spinner: UIActivityIndicatorView = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 150, 150)) as UIActivityIndicatorView

if firstNameTF.text != "" &&  lastNameTF.text != "" && newUsernameTF.text != "" && newPasswordTF.text != "" && emailTF.text != "" && phoneNumberTF.text != "" {

    let newUser = PFUser()

    if let profilePictureImage = profilePictureIV?.image {
        let profilePicture = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(profilePictureImage, 1)!
        let profilePictureImageFile = PFFile(data: profilePicture)
        newUser["profilePicture"] = profilePictureImageFile
    }
    newUser["firstName"] = firstNameTF.text
    newUser["lastName"] = lastNameTF.text
    newUser.username = newUsernameTF.text
    newUser.password = newPasswordTF.text
    newUser.email = emailTF.text
    newUser["phoneNumber"] = phoneNumberTF.text

    newUser.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (succeeded: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if let error = error {
            spinner.startAnimating()
            self.alert("Opps", textMessage: (error.localizedDescription))
        } else {
            spinner.startAnimating()
            self.alert("Congratualtion!", textMessage: "Success, your account has been created.")
            callSegue()
        }
    }
} else {
    alert("Hmm...", textMessage: "If you want an account, please fill in the blanks.")
}
}

func callSegue()
{
   self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showMessages", sender: self)
}
```

Comment: Of course you can.  If you use self in a block and pass the block to an object which retains it and `self` retains that object then you will get a retain cycle but that won't be the case here.  Calling `performSegueWithIdentifer` directly or in another function makes no difference

Comment: if you pass the self than you receive that compilation error(Implicit use of 'self' in closure; use 'self.' to make capture semantics explicit)

Comment: What compilation error? `sender` is of type `id` so it will certainly accept a `UIViewController` subclass which is what `self` will be in this case

Comment: You get that message when you try and invoke another instance function  in a block, passing self, without specifying `self.` in front of the function, which you should always do for instance functions and properties whether it is required or not (You didn't do this when you called `callSegue` for example, which is poor style).  You can specify `self` as an argument to a function in a block.  Put this into a playground as an example - https://gist.github.com/paulw11/30522b7f61d0a081e520